# install tomcat as windows service without service.bat file or msi

Tags: windows, tomcat, installation, service

I need to install tomcat as windows service on windows 10. currently we use service.bat file to remove and install tomcat9. however  would like to avoid there dependency as when version is updated I have update there file. is there a way to install tomcat as a windows service without having to use service.bat file or msi?